# Setting main container height to 100vh gives window.scrollY position 0 in React app

Tags: css, reactjs, firefox, safari, flicker

I wanted to solve the flashing issues in the safari / Firefox browser. Setting the main container height to `max-height: 100vh` solved the flickering issue, but I also need to track the `window.scrollY` position. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here Main container height = 100vh. But `window.scrollY` gives the value in pixels. We need to have height in pixels to get `window.scrollY` position.